# how to replace value of drop down list selected item to some value on change event of text box in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown list and a textbox. I am trying to replace the dropdown list selected value to some value by changing the text in textbox.

Here is my code:

```
<select class="form-control Series-1 valid" name="CRMFields" id="CRMFields">
    <option>None</option>
    <optgroup label="Lead Information"></optgroup>
    <option value="First Name^Lead ID^">Lead ID</option>
    <option value="First Name^First Name^" selected="">First Name</option>
    <option value="First Name^Last Name^">Last Name</option>
</select>
<input class="defaultValue" data-target-class="Series-1" id="DefaultValue" name="DefaultValue" type="text" value="">
```

JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".defaultValue").change(function () {
            var thisval = $(this).val();
            var targetclass = $(this).attr("data-target-class");
            var CRMFiledValue = $("." + targetclass).val();
            var arr = CRMFiledValue.split('^');
            var left = arr[0];
            var middle = arr[1];
            var last = thisval;
            var replaceText = left + "^" + middle + "^" + last;
            alert(replaceText);
            alert($("." + targetclass).prop("value", replaceText));
            alert($("." + targetclass).val());               
        });
    });
</script>
```

But above code showing me [object Object] and null on the alert box instead of concatenated value.

I want to replace the selected item of value to some value on Change event of text box.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sridharnetha/tzbgvrne/)

I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: I'm a bit confused at what you're trying to accomplish. I created a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9omrxvpq/). Can you tell me exactly what it needs to do? Give me an example (Like if I type asdf in the field, what should happen)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you are changing the value of every single option whenever someone changes the value of the input box.

so I added `+ option:selected` to the selector of the `var CRMFiledValue`. I assume this is what you were going for because you probably didn't want every field to have `FirstName^FirstName^thisval` as it's value. The below code was tested and worked according to how your HTML/other javascript was set up

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".defaultValue").change(function () {
            var thisval = $(this).val();
            var targetclass = $(this).attr("data-target-class");
        
            var CRMFiledValue = $("." + targetclass + ' option:selected').val();
            var arr = CRMFiledValue.split('^');
            var left = arr[0];
            var middle = arr[1];
            var last = thisval;
            var replaceText = left + "^" + middle + "^" + last;        
        
            $("." + targetclass + ' option:selected').prop("value", replaceText);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change:

```
$("." + targetclass).prop("value", replaceText);
```

To:

```
$("." + targetclass + ' option:selected').val(replaceText);
```

And always bear in mind that this operation does not return a scalar value and will therefore return [Object Object] to `alert( ... )`. A better debug function would be `console.log( .... )`:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/tzbgvrne/1/)